# How to mimic the enyo.Popup behavior

Tags: event-handling, popup, enyo

I am currently trying to mimic the `enyo.Popup` behavior. I looked at the [source](https://github.com/enyojs/enyo/blob/master/source/ui/Popup.js) at `github` but having a hard time to understand it.

Especially that is the code I have trouble with:

```
handlers: {
    //...
    onRequestShow: "requestShow",
    onRequestHide: "requestHide"
},

//* @public
events: {
    //* Fires after the popup is shown.
    onShow: "",
    //* Fires after the popup is hidden.
    onHide: ""
},
```

And some where else in the code, there are calls to `this.show()`.

Firstly, I did not found a declaration for `this.show()`. Secondly, though I assume that it must be inside `this.show()` and `this.hide()` respectively, where are the `onShow` and `onHide` events called?

And lastly, I defined a kind of myself, containing also the above code. But despite the `show()` and `hide()` methods are working, my own `requestShow()` and `requestHide()` methods were not called.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, `show` is a function declared on enyo.Control: http://enyojs.com/api/#enyo.Control::show

`onShow` and `onHide` are events that can be subscribed to by the popup's owner (hence, their declaration in the events block).  They are called in the `showingChanged` function.  The method for calling events is do{EventNameWithoutOn}. In this case:  `doShow`.

Check this documentation on events: https://github.com/enyojs/enyo/wiki/Event-Handling
(Or, you could buy my nice Enyo book!  http://roysutton.com/2013/01/31/print-book-now-available/ )

The handlers block is a way for a control to subscribe to messages it (or its children) generate. Having said that, I don't see any place in the code that generates `onRequestHide` events.

I hope that helps!